# NLog multiple log factories

Tags: c#, logging, nlog

`LogManager` is a singleton class with `LogFactory` inside.
Is there any problem with having multiple `LogFactories` instances in the running process? In my situation this could be possible because some components that I use are using internally `Nlog logging` and the main process can also use NLog using different configuration files.

It could be any problem if the factories are created like this way instead of using `LogManager.LogFactory`?

```
var logFactory = new LogFactory(new XmlLoggingConfiguration("file1.Nlog.config");
var logFactory2 = new LogFactory(new XmlLoggingConfiguration("file2.Nlog.config");
```

Comment: Having multiple `LogFactory`-instances is fully supported, as also written here: https://github.com/NLog/NLog/wiki/Configure-component-logging

Comment: @RolfKristensen Thanks for your comment. I was almost sure that was supported but I wanted to confirm. You can answer if you want the question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

NLog fully supports having multiple `LogFactory`-instances.

As also written here: https://github.com/NLog/NLog/wiki/Configure-component-logging